# Fatal signal 11 (SIGSEGV), code 2, fault addr 0x747f580bf0 in tid 10572 (Dart Profiler S)

Tags: android, flutter

I develop a flutter app. It works fine on recent android versions. but when I run it on android 6.0 suddenly it crashes with error. can anyone help me? Did it happen to you?

Fatal signal 11 (SIGSEGV), code 2, fault addr 0x747f580bf0 in tid 10572 (Dart Profiler S)

```
  A  Fatal signal 11 (SIGSEGV), code 2, fault addr 0x747f580bf0 in tid 10572 (Dart Profiler S)
                         
  pid: 10495, tid: 10572, name: Dart Profiler S  >>> com.lunyx.persiangulf_hld <<<                  
     #00 pc 0000000000827dc4  /data/app/com.lunyx.persiangulf_hld-2/lib/arm64/libflutter.so (offset 0x1b87000)                
     #01 pc 0000000000636e0c  /data/app/com.lunyx.persiangulf_hld-2/lib/arm64/libflutter.so (offset 0x1b87000)
```